# What is the tag in facebook API in iFrame for username?

Tags: php, facebook

I use this in FMBL = `echo "<p>Hello, <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\" />!</p>";`

But it dont work on the iFrame option. What i need to do in order to see the user name in a iFrame? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the username provided you have the user ID with the API as followed:

```
$user_details = $facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($user_id, array('last_name','first_name','name','pic_small','pic','pic_big'));

echo $user_details[0]['name'];
```

Link: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getInfo